# Как установить xdebug на Apache2.4 Windows

Tags: php, apache, xdebug

Скачиваю xdebug xdebug.org/download.php
в php.ini прописываю

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = 'C:/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.3.3-5.6-vc11-nts-x86_64.dll'
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
```

и без полного адреса тоже пробовал.
Апач перезагружал.

В итоге делаю phpinfo() и он просто не видит ничего

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: php.ini-то точно тот редактируется? просто `extension=...` пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

В документации написано, что если используется Windows, то переменная в php.ini будет называться не zend_extension, а **zend_extension_ts**.
http://www.xdebug.ru/install-xdebug

Comment: там-то как раз nts

Comment: все я разобрался, просто версию нужно было без nts

Comment: @modelfak, напишите это, пожалуйста, в виде ответа. тем самым вы, вполне вероятно, поможете другим людям найти решение их проблемы, ведь, в частности, комментарии просто не индексируются поисковиками.